# Tradução de linguagens de programação

Tags: característica-linguagem

Sempre que pesquiso sobre "tradução de linguagem de programação no Google" só me aparecem tutoriais de como reescrever de uma linguagem para outra, e nunca o que realmente quero saber: **Existe alguma linguagem de programação que foi traduzida para o português?**

Vejo isso por que me intriga o fato de haverem várias linguagens de programação em inglês e pouquíssimas (Conheço apenas [BIRL](https://birl-language.github.io/) e Portugol*) em português ou em outros idiomas.

Por exemplo o Python, uma linguagem simples e poderosa. Existe legalmente algo que impede a tradução da linguagem para se tornar uma linguagem de apresentação para iniciantes na área?

#### Existe alguma barreira que proíbe isso que vá além da simples tradução das palavras reservadas?

Comment: Não, inclusive conheço pessoas que estão trabalhando em uma versão do Python em português.

Comment: Existe um fator importante sobre não existir em tantos outros idiomas: público alvo. Sejamos sinceros, a língua franca após a Segunda Guerra Mundial se tornou o inglês, e muita coisa na computação começou com pessoas cuja língua mãe era o inglês ou em instituições que estavam em países cuja língua principal era o inglês, fazendo disso, portanto, um legado sociológico linguístico importante na área

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não, não existe uma barreira. Um compilador é apenas mais um peça de *software*. Nada impede alguém de fazer um *fork*  de um compilador / interpretador qualquer, traduzir palavras reservadas e eventualmente localizar a liguagem.

O Excel por exemplo possui fórmulas localizadas. Inclusive, até onde vai meu conhecimento, não é possível mudar a língua das fórmulas sem instalar um *Language Pack*. Bem, a Microsoft ao menos teve a decência de matar o VBA localizado nos anos 90. O problema com *macros* em Alemão, Francês, etc seria com certeza muito pior do que o problema das fórmulas.

As perguntas subentendidas são: Então por que essa não é uma prática mais popular? Por que não traduzimos e adotamos linguagens em Português?

Ao meu ver as desvantagens não justificam as vantagens de localização. Voltando ao Excel: Tente parear com um colega Francês e usar o Excel no *laptop* dele (sim, eu vivi isso). Mesmo que seu ambiente de trabalho não seja tão globalizado há desvantagens na localização. Após se acostumar com o Excel em Português, tente abrir uma planilha no Excel em Inglês e editar as fórmulas (ou vice-versa)... Não, não é divertido.

O Inglês é a língua franca da computação, assim como o Italiano é a língua franca da música e o Latim é ainda hoje fortemente usado em nomenclatura científica.

Enquanto traduzir "if" para "se", "while" para "enquanto", "or" para "ou", etc pode facilitar - até certo ponto - a vida de um lusófono, me pergunto se essa é uma barreira cognitiva tão significativa assim... 
Na data que escrevi essa resposta o Java possui 57 palavras reservadas, Python possui 33. Quando consideramos tudo o que um programador tem que aprender, o uso dessas palavras reservadas em Inglês me parece um problema menor. Eu trabalhei e estudei por muitos anos com programadores muito bons que não falam Inglês.

As palavras reservadas também são só o começo do problema. O que fazer com toda a biblioteca padrão da linguagem? Devemos traduzir também?  E o que fazer com nomes de variáveis (que inclusive podem conflitar com palavras reservadas)? O que fazer com literais (separadores decimais, datas, etc)? Devemos portar e traduzir todas as bibliotecas e *frameworks*?

A tradução de uma linguagem resulta em... bem... outra linguagem. Uma linguagem talvez mais acessível para a comunidade local; porém incompatível, quando não totalmente inacessível para a comunidade original. O resultado final são ecossistemas separados, reinvenção da roda e um esforço enorme para portar *software* entre duas linguagens.

O lado positivo da localização é a inclusão (vide Stackoverflow PT). O lado negativo é a fragmentação.

Pense em uma realidade alternativa em que a linguagem Lua tivesse sido criada usando palavras reservadas em Português. Ela talvez tivesse encontrado um nicho, ao menos temporariamente, na Petrobrás e nas atividades de pesquisa da PUC do Rio. Quem sabe Lua teria até um pézinho em outras empresas e Universidades nacionais. Hoje porém muito provavelmente Lua seria uma relíquia do passado. Esse mundo hipotético teria perdido muito... Instituições como Adobe, Blizzard, Mozilla, NASA, etc não teriam a chance de fazer coisas fantásticas com uma linguagem criada aqui no Brasil.

---

**Fonte**: [SOEn - Do there exist any compilers with localized versions of programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288061/do-there-exist-any-compilers-with-localized-versions-of-programming-languages)

Comment: Hmm, seria essa a razão da "morte" do Portugol? (Pelo menos na minha região parece ter desaparecido um pouco).

Comment: Concluindo, num mundo do rei inglês, devemos criar algo universal. Por esse ponto, quando nós, brasileiros, resolvemos criar uma biblioteca, _frameworks_, e até mesmo "softwares que podem receber acessos mundiais", deveríamos escrever em inglês?

Comment: @Breno, sobre o primeiro ponto, vejo o Portugol mais como uma ferramenta de ensino. Um pseudocódigo que ganhou alguns compiladores e ferramentas derivados, ainda primariamente para suporte de atividades acadêmicas (Visualalg, Portugol Studio, etc). Sobre o segundo ponto, minha resposta é um categórico sim. Não só deveríamos, já o fazemos. Uso várias ferramentas, bibliotecas, frameworks e APIs de código aberto inicialmente desenvolvidas por brasileiros (e.g., htop, VRaptor e várias APIs do Java que nasceram em JSRs lideradas por experts Brasileiros).

Comment: Eu usei o Dialog, também conhecido como dBase pirateado na caruda e traduzido para o português, e que fez muito dinheiro vendendo pra estatais que eram obrigadas comprar o "similar" nacional. Era "lindo".